# CRM - QualifyResponse only returning one entity when two are being created

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm having an issue using the "QualifyLeadResponse" class from CRM. I'm using "QualifyLeadRequest" to create an Opportunity and a Contact, but when I get the response it only contains the Opportunity.

However, if I go into CRM and look it does create a contact. As you can see from the screenshot the count is only 1 for entities, even though there were two created. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Why would only one entity be returned? [image]

```
 QualifyLeadRequest qualifyLead = new QualifyLeadRequest
                        {
                            LeadId = new EntityReference(crmLead.LogicalName, leadId),
                            Status = new OptionSetValue(3),
                            CreateOpportunity = true,
                            CreateContact = true
                        };


                        Console.WriteLine("Lead created.");

                        var qualifyIntoOpportunityAndContact = (QualifyLeadResponse)userProxy.Execute(qualifyLead);
                        Console.WriteLine("Lead qualified.");
                        foreach (var entity in qualifyIntoOpportunityAndContact.CreatedEntities)
                        {
                            if (entity.LogicalName == "opportunity")
                            {
                                opportunity.Id = entity.Id;
                                userProxy.Update(opportunity);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Code seems fine.  The 2016 SDK shows that more fields are required in the request message, maybe try supplying all properties on the request to see if that changes anything.  Otherwise, feels like it could be a platform bug.  If you're on prem, you could enable tracing to see if any errors are being swallowed, though that seems unlikely.

Comment: Does the Lead happen to already have a contact associated with it?